# Displaying images stored in a database using PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html, image, blob, echo

I want to display the Images I've stored in my database in this HTML table. I've stored the files as 'BLOB' and I'd like the Images to be displayed under the 'Photo' column. What code do I use to echo out the images?

```
    <table wactidth='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' align="center">
    <thead align='left'>
        <th>Photo</th>
        <th>Act Name</th>   
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Number of People</th>
        <th>Actions</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($acts as $act):?>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- I WANT TO DISPLAY THE IMAGES UNDER THIS COLUMN--></td>
            <td><?php echo $act['ActName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $act['Genre'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $act['ContactFirstName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $act['ContactLastName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $act['NumberOfPeople'];?></td>
            <td><a href="?editact&actid=<?php echo $act['actid'];?>">Edit</a>|<a href="?delete&actid=<?php echo $act['actid'];?>">Delete</a>|<a href="upload&actid=<?php echo $act['actid'];?>">Upload Image</td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you running into problems?  Have you considered just storing references to filesystem paths to the images in your database rather than the files themselves (in most typical cases this is probably better practice).

Comment: @JamHack How would you just store the images outside of the database?  By just saving them on your file system and having a field in the DB that contains the filepath like `/path/to/file/in/web/root/file.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing just the paths to the images, like "/path/to/your/image.jpg". Then you can echo out the path just like a string

```
<td><img src="<?php echo $act['imagepath'];?>" alt="" /></td>
```

Comment: How do I store just the path to the image? Is there a way to do that using SQL?

Comment: you would store it just like any string. like a name, or place or whatever